# How do i know if a number is octal?

Tags: assembly

I'm supposed to write an asm program that sequence of octal digits until the carriage return. It's supposed to tell if the user entered a legal or an illegal octal number. How am i going to be able to know that? is there an equation for it?

Comment: Check if all digits are in the range 0..7?

Comment: `octal` is a representation ( a way to represent numbers ) not a class or family of numbers, I don't understand the question.

Comment: There can be no equation for it. Equations operate on numbers, and number don't have a base. A number isn't octal any more than it's decimal or binary. You'll have to check the input *string*.

Comment: maybe you mean something like a modulo operation ? modulo of 8 ?

Comment: When the user enters **01245637**, the output should be **Legal octal number**, but when he enters **156274079**, the output should be **Illegal octal number**. So, i only have to check that each number is from0-6, right?:)

Comment: Nope, it should be 0-7

Comment: I've done that, but i don't know why it keeps telling me it's legal even when it's not :( I will post the code above if you need to see

Comment: Is the way i compared the input with the characters '0' and '7' right?

Comment: Your code is written so that any character >= '0' will be allowed, even if it's greater than '7' (the second check won't be performed).

Comment: How do i make sure that it's in the range 0..7, if i check 7 first, there will be a problem, too, right?

Comment: All natural numbers can be represented in octal or whatever base system. Base 7 is my favourite but alas never caught on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of jumping back to input after comparing to 0, you need to jump to the comparison with 7 if the comparision succeeds, and jump to output the illegal string if it fails.